# GQL db.Model default parameter value

Tags: google-app-engine, model

I found it kinda troublesome or difficult to find exact example I wanted for GQL.

Given the following:

```
class Sample (db.Model):
    name = db.StringProperty(required=True) 
    type = db.StringProperty(required=False)
```

How do I set default parameter value.Let's say, I want to set **type** parameter to the value of "new" when I do following:

```
Sample(name="Yeah").put()
```

What would be the format of setting the default parameter value for a class inherited db.Model ?

Comment: I can't understand what your question is, nor what it has to do with the GQL language. You seem to be asking about the Model API.

Comment: This doesn't have anything to do with GQL :)

Comment: Sorry. My bad to have misunderstood the tag. I've edited it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add "default" parameter in the definition of your type, like this:

```
class Test(db.Model):
    Test = db.StringProperty(default="test")
```